# Comparing scalars to Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, variables, numpy, astropy

What I am trying to do is make a table based on a piece-wise function in Python. For example, say I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table, Column
from astropy.io import ascii
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = x * 2
data = Table([x, y], names = ['x', 'y'])
ascii.write(data, "xytable.dat")
xytable = ascii.read("xytable.dat")
print xytable
```

This works as expected, it prints a table that has `x` values 1 through 5 and `y` values 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

But, what if I instead want `y` to be `x * 2` only if `x` is 3 or less, and `y` to be `x + 2` otherwise?

If I add:

```
if x > 3: 
    y = x + 2
```

it says:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How do I code my table so that it works as a piece-wise function? How do I compare scalars to Numpy arrays?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Astropy or the Table class. It's just how you read in your data. You should tag your question "numpy" and just use numpy arrays x, y directly for the example. To do what you want, use [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [numpy.choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).

Comment: @Christoph: good point; updated tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly use [`numpy.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where):

```
In [196]: y = np.where(x > 3, x + 2, y)

In [197]: y
Out[197]: array([2, 4, 6, 6, 7])
```

The code above gets the job done in a fully vectorized manner. This approach is generally more efficient (and arguably more elegant) than using list comprehensions and type conversions.

Comment: It does output the right array, but it doesn't change the y values permanently, which I need to create the table. Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: You simply has to assign the output to `y`. Edited my answer to show you how `y` gets actually changed.

Comment: alright yeah. I overlooked that. Thanks a bunch again!

Answer (score 1):

Start off not using numpy (or maybe you can, I don't know numpy) and just do in using regular python lists.

```
x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
y = [ i * 2 if i < 3 else i + 2 for i in x ]
print y
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Then you can make it a numpy array:

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
```